# Remote installation of mysql got stuck

Tags: server, bash, scripts, mysql, password

I have written a script to install some set of packages to a list of servers. When i execute the script mysql installation got stuck at "enter the root password" section. Is there anything i need to modify in my script ? Advice me.

Is there any way to pass the mysql root password through the script itself ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
Servers_list=/opt/servers_list
for Host in $(< $Servers_list )
do
echo "Installing package on $Host"
#ssh "${Host}" apt-get -y install "${PackageName}"
ssh "${Host}" apt-get update $$ apt-get -y install apache2 apache2-doc apache2-utils mysql-server
done
```

[image: The password screen is different and it stuck here]

[image: The usual password config window for mysql setup]

Comment: The 1st picture is what i got while installing mysql via script, the 2nd picture is the mysql password page when i install the software in the server directly without any script

Comment: Also the script installs packages on the first server alone, remaing servers are skipped showing "all packages are up to date" event hough there is no such package  (apache2 in this case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
Servers_list=/opt/servers_list
for Host in $(< $Servers_list )
do
  echo "Installing package on $Host"
  ssh "${Host}" "echo 'mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server/root_password password your_password' | debconf-set-selections && \  
    echo 'mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server/root_password_again password your_password' | debconf-set-selections && \  
    apt-get update && \  
    apt-get -y install apache2 apache2-doc apache2-utils mysql-server"
done
```

If you have a lot of server you should consider using a tool like ansible or puppet.

#### Edit :

- Backslash (\) are used for readability.  They allow to continue the command on a next line.
- AND (&&) operator is used to exec many command on the same line.  If one fail the next is not executed.
- debconf-set-selections is used to preset configs.  In this case : password.  You can find more information on it inside the man page by typing : `man debconf-set-selections` inside terminal.

Comment: what exactly debconf does, its little strange to understand, and why you added \ symbol next to &&

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect your questions.

Comment: The script worked perfectly, appreciate your help